# Facebook comment plugin does not get posted to my profile

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook comment plugin on my website, when I comment on it, it shows on my website, but doesnt show on my profile on facebook. I had the post on profile option ticked and it still doesnt show. is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You must create an application in facebook and then add meta tags to your site

```
<meta content='{YOUR APP ID}' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='YOUR FACEBOOK ID' property='fb:admins'/>
```

You can create application [here](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: I have an app and it seems to work at times and not work some other times. I think its a problem with facebook. Its working now all of a sudden